# Dagger hilt testing EntryPointAccessors

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, dagger-hilt, mockk

Hi I have a Class that implements an abstraction with a parameter of type *Foo* and is being provided through an EntryPointAccessors directly into the abstract class. Something like this

```
SomethingImportantBuilderImpl(
    ...
): AbstractSomethingImportantBuilder(
    foo: Foo = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(applicationContext, FooEntryPoint::class.java).provideFoo()
)
```

Everything is working as expected but now how do I provide the *Foo* through EntryPointAccessor to the SomethingImportantBuilder in a unit test?

Everytime test is ran it says the next:

```
Could not find an Application in the given context: null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an Application in the given context: null
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.Contexts.getApplication(Contexts.java:42)
    at dagger.hilt.android.EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(EntryPointAccessors.java:37)
```

Any help/suggestion? How can I provide this dependency in unit test? Also using Mockk.

Edit 1: If I try to mock it like this:

`every { EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(any(), FooEntryPoint::class.java).provideFoo() } returns mockk(relaxed = true)`

throws the next error: `android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()Landroid/content/Context;`

Edit 2: Tried to use Mockk so I mock the **FooEntryPoint interface where hilt implements under the hood this entry point in a Singleton/Context interface**. not working as it doesn't initialize the context:

```
private lateinit var context: Application

@Before
fun setup(){
    context = mockk(moreInterfaces = arrayOf(FooEntryPoint::class, GeneratedComponent::class), relaxed = true)
}

@Test
fun useContext(){
    println(context) //using context throws the error saying that lateinit var is not initialized.
}
```

Error `lateinit property context has not been initialized kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property context has not been initialized`

Still the same problem. How do I provide the applicationContext for the EntryPoint?

Comment: Did you follow this Hilt Testing setup? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOp_CEP_EjM

Comment: That setup is for instrumentation tests, mine is a unit test @muetzenflo

Comment: In that case the answer is easy: It won't work. UnitTests are not having AndroidContext. They are only possible for pure Kotlin code (non-Android logic). As soon as you need something like `Context` or `Application` (which is part of Hilt), you need to use instrumentation tests. 
Disclaimer: I am not a testing pro and there is a chance that I am talking bullshit right now. But I am quite confident that Hilt is not usable in pure UnitTests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah that's what I thought, question is, can I run instrumentation tests like unit tests? I'm also not experienced in testing, but if somehow could get the application context and pass to hilt would be amazing. That'd require to setup it like that which I haven't tried yet but will look forward to do it if it's possible.

Comment: It's possible, yes. But only as instrumentation tests. Don't worry though, once the emulator is ready, they are also pretty quick. To set everything up, watch the youtube video. Then you can inject the ApplicationContext just like in the app module.

Comment: Alright, I'll test in a less than 2 days, if it works I'll tell you to post the correct answer.  Thank you!

Comment: I added an detailed answer that may at least help others in the future and to make the bounty worth it :)

Answer (score 2):

You are facing two different issues:

1. Using Hilt in an UnitTest
2. Need to inject an applicationContext in a UnitTest

ad 1) I am 90% sure that you cannot use Hilt in UnitTests, but I will happily update this answer if someone provides differnt information.
Why is it not possible to use Hilt in UnitTests? For the same reason as number 2 (see below), since Hilt is tightly coupled to the AndroidFramework.

ad 2) This is definitely not possible and actually the main difference between UnitTests and instrumentation tests on Android: The latter are running within an Android environment (real device, emulator, etc.). Because of that it is possible to test components of your code that are using Android classes. Most famously `ApplicationContext`, `Context`, `Activity` and `Fragment`. UnitTests on the other hand are raw logic-tests and unrelated to any Android framework components. No Android class is needed for UnitTest. No Android class is possible for UnitTests.

So in your case, you want to use Hilt for a test that needs the ApplicationContext injected. Both are strong indicators that you have to do that in an instrumentation test. Here is a step-by-step instruction how to setup hilt for instrumentation tests as described in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOp_CEP_EjM

1. add the following gradle dependencies:

```
androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.38.1" 
kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-comiler:2.38.1"
```

2. To use Hilt, you need to swap out the `AndroidJUnitRunner` with a small custom Runner. To do so, create this `HiltTestRunner`:

```
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltTestApplication

class HiltTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, className: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

3. To tell gradle about the new test runner, open your `/app/build.gradle` and exchange this line:

`testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`

with the class reference of the `HiltTestRunner` you just created:

`testInstrumentationRunner "your.package.HiltTestRunner"`

That's it basically. Now you can create a new Module in your test folders just like you would do in the normal app folder. For example:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class TestDatabaseModule {
    
    @Provides
    @Named("test_database")
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext applicationContext: Context): MyDatabase {
        return Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(applicationContext, MyDatabase::class.java)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
    }
}
```

To inject this database in your TestCode, you need to create a `HiltAndroidRule` and call `hiltRule.inject()` in the `@Before` method:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class UserDaoTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule
    val testCoroutineRule = TestCoroutineRule()

    @Inject
    lateinit var database: MyDatabase

    private lateinit var sut: UserDao

    @Before
    fun createDb() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        sut = database.userDao()
    }

    @After
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun closeDb() {
        database.clearAllTables()
        database.close()
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun insertAndGetUserFromDb_success() = testCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {

        // Given a database with 1 user
        val newUser = UserFakes.get()

        sut.insert(newUser)

        // When fetching the user
        sut.get().test {

            // Then the user fields should match 
            val user = awaitItem()
            assert(user.id == newUser.id)
            assert(user.name == newUser.name)
        }

    }
}
```

Additionsl treat: I am using [Turbine](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine) to simplify testing Flows. This is the part in the code above where I call `.test {}` on a Flow and `awaitItem()` to wait for the result of the Flow. See the Turbine readme.md for more information.

Comment: Yes you can use Hilt and use android framework classes in unit tests.  You need to make sure you are using Robolectric which provides all the jvm test fakes for the android framework classes.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to do it in unit test and not instrumentation test. In this case you need to mock `applicationContext` and `EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication`

You didn't post your whole code so not sure where your applicationContext came from, suppose you are using dependency injection from the constructor, you need to pass in a mocked `applicationContext` instance built using `mockk<Context>()`

After that, the key to mock `EntryPointAccessors` is to use `mockkStatic`

```
mockkStatic(EntryPointAccessors::class)
every { EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(any(), FooEntryPoint::class.java) } returns mockk(relaxed = true) {
    every { provideFoo() } returns mockk() // Further provide customized 'Foo' instance if needed
}
```

and you should be good to go.